# Why I get an invalid schema error in a servlet, with same code in main function not?

Tags: jpa, intellij-idea, mariadb, criteria-api, apache-tomee

I have a project with some students.
An RefugeeWelcome Website with:

- TomEE 1.7.3 (Plume Version)
- MariaDB: Server version: 10.1.10-MariaDB-1~jessie-log mariadb.org binary distribution
- IDE: IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2
- JRE: 1.8.0_51

---

To get data from DB I am using Criteria API / JPA.

Here the working main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("RefugEEWelcomeApp");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();


    CriteriaQuery<TblProductCategoryEntity> query = builder.createQuery(TblProductCategoryEntity.class);

    Root<TblProductCategoryEntity> productCategoryEntityRoot = query.from(TblProductCategoryEntity.class);

    Predicate mainCatNull = builder.isNull(productCategoryEntityRoot.get(TblProductCategoryEntity_.maincategory));

    query.select(productCategoryEntityRoot).where(mainCatNull);

    List<TblProductCategoryEntity> results = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();


    for(Object o:results)
    {
        TblProductCategoryEntity e=(TblProductCategoryEntity) o;
        System.out.println(
                "ID : "+e.getIdtblProductCategory()
                +"\tAtt: "+e.getAttachments()
                +"\tCAT: "+e.getMaincategory());
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
[EL Info]: 2015-12-29 19:26:22.731--ServerSession(1275240546)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3
[EL Info]: connection: 2015-12-29 19:26:23.705--ServerSession(1275240546)--/file:/C:/Users/the-l/IdeaProjects/RefugEE3/out/production/RefugEE3/_RefugEEWelcomeApp login successful
ID : 1  Att: ...    CAT: null
ID : 8  Att: ...    CAT: null
...
```

---

Here my servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("RefugEEWelcomeApp");
    EntityManager em        = emf.createEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<TblProductCategoryEntity> query = builder.createQuery(TblProductCategoryEntity.class);

    Root<TblProductCategoryEntity> productCategoryEntityRoot = query.from(TblProductCategoryEntity.class);

    Predicate mainCatNull = builder.isNull(productCategoryEntityRoot.get(TblProductCategoryEntity_.maincategory));

    query.select(productCategoryEntityRoot).where(mainCatNull);

    List<TblProductCategoryEntity> results = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();

    List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> subCat = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Object o: results){
        TblProductCategoryEntity e=(TblProductCategoryEntity) o;
        urls.add(e.getAttachments());
        subCat.add(e.getIdtblProductCategory());
        System.out.println(e.getAttachments());
        System.out.println(e.getIdtblProductCategory());
    }

    request.setAttribute("img", urls);
    request.setAttribute("id", subCat);

    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/category.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

---

TomEE log and Browser output to call servlet:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException

type Exception report

message Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: invalid schema name: REFUGEESWELCOMEAPP
Error Code: -4850
Call: SELECT idtbl_product_category, attachments, maincategory FROM RefugeesWelcomeApp.tbl_product_category WHERE (maincategory IS NULL)
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=TblProductCategoryEntity sql="SELECT idtbl_product_category, attachments, maincategory FROM RefugeesWelcomeApp.tbl_product_category WHERE (maincategory IS NULL)")
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:382)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:473)
    ra.servlets.getMainCategoryNative.doGet(getMainCategoryNative.java:31)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: invalid schema name: REFUGEESWELCOMEAPP
Error Code: -4850
Call: SELECT idtbl_product_category, attachments, maincategory FROM RefugeesWelcomeApp.tbl_product_category WHERE (maincategory IS NULL)
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=TblProductCategoryEntity sql="SELECT idtbl_product_category, attachments, maincategory FROM RefugeesWelcomeApp.tbl_product_category WHERE (maincategory IS NULL)")
    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:684)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2055)
    org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2740)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2693)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:559)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1175)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1134)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:460)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1222)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:473)
    ra.servlets.getMainCategoryNative.doGet(getMainCategoryNative.java:31)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: invalid schema name: REFUGEESWELCOMEAPP
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1565)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1514)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:778)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:621)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2055)
    org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2740)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2693)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:559)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1175)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1134)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:460)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1222)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:473)
    ra.servlets.getMainCategoryNative.doGet(getMainCategoryNative.java:31)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid schema name: REFUGEESWELCOMEAPP
    org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getSchemaHsqlName(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getSchemaName(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.Session.getSchemaName(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getTable(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadFromClause(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableExpression(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1565)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1514)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:778)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:621)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2055)
    org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2740)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2693)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:559)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1175)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1134)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:460)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1222)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:473)
    ra.servlets.getMainCategoryNative.doGet(getMainCategoryNative.java:31)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.63 (1.7.3) logs.

Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.63 (1.7.3)
```

---

[image: MariaDB: Schema: RefugeesWelcomeApp incl. all tables]

This picture is an screenshot from IntelliJ about the DB.

Schema: RefugeesWelcomeApp

incl. all tables

Question: Have someone any idea what my fault is?
Is MariaDB context sensitive? If yes, how can manage that?
Or did IntelliJ some compile mistakes and write all letters big for the schema?

Edit: If i delete in the model class the schema tag, i get following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException

type Exception report

message Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: TBL_PRODUCT_CATEGORY
Error Code: -5501
Call: SELECT idtbl_product_category, attachments, maincategory FROM tbl_product_category WHERE (maincategory IS NULL)
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=TblProductCategoryEntity sql="SELECT idtbl_product_category, attachments, maincategory FROM tbl_product_category WHERE (maincategory IS NULL)")
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:382)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:473)
    ra.servlets.getMainCategoryNative.doGet(getMainCategoryNative.java:31)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: TBL_PRODUCT_CATEGORY
Error Code: -5501
Call: SELECT idtbl_product_category, attachments, maincategory FROM tbl_product_category WHERE (maincategory IS NULL)
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=TblProductCategoryEntity sql="SELECT idtbl_product_category, attachments, maincategory FROM tbl_product_category WHERE (maincategory IS NULL)")
    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:684)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2055)
    org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2740)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2693)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:559)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1175)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1134)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:460)
    org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1222)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:473)
    ra.servlets.getMainCategoryNative.doGet(getMainCategoryNative.java:31)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: TBL_PRODUCT_CATEGORY
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)...
```

---

percistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="RefugEEWelcomeApp" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>ra.model.RltnProductCategoryEntity</class>
        <class>ra.model.RltnProductCategoryLanguageEntity</class>
        <class>ra.model.RltnProductCategoryShopCategoryEntity</class>
        <class>ra.model.RltnProductLanguageEntity</class>
        <class>ra.model.RltnProductShopcategoryEntity</class>
        <class>ra.model.RltnShopCategoryLanguageEntity</class>
        <class>ra.model.TblLanguageEntity</class>
        <class>ra.model.TblProductEntity</class>
        <class>ra.model.TblProductCategoryEntity</class>
        <class>ra.model.TblShopCategoryEntity</class>
        <class>ra.model.TblShopsEntity</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/RefugeesWelcomeApp"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

---

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet>
        <description>Getting MainCat ID for Subcat searching</description>
        <servlet-name>getMainCat</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ra.servlets.getMainCategory</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>getMainCat</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/getMainCat</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

---

Table class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_product_category", schema = "RefugeesWelcomeApp")
public class TblProductCategoryEntity {
    private int idtblProductCategory;
    private Integer maincategory;
    private String attachments;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idtbl_product_category")
    public int getIdtblProductCategory() {
        return idtblProductCategory;
    }

    public void setIdtblProductCategory(int idtblProductCategory) {
        this.idtblProductCategory = idtblProductCategory;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "maincategory")
    public Integer getMaincategory() {
        return maincategory;
    }

    public void setMaincategory(Integer maincategory) {
        this.maincategory = maincategory;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "attachments")
    public String getAttachments() {
        return attachments;
    }

    public void setAttachments(String attachments) {
        this.attachments = attachments;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        TblProductCategoryEntity that = (TblProductCategoryEntity) o;

        if (idtblProductCategory != that.idtblProductCategory) return false;
        if (maincategory != null ? !maincategory.equals(that.maincategory) : that.maincategory != null) return false;
        if (attachments != null ? !attachments.equals(that.attachments) : that.attachments != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = idtblProductCategory;
        result = 31 * result + (maincategory != null ? maincategory.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (attachments != null ? attachments.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>` AND `<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>` looks suspicious. Just to rule that one out: Why don't you have some credentials here?

Comment: @MWiesner jdbc.user and jdbc.password have no credentials only here for the question, normaly it exist in percistence.xml

Comment: So check my advice of the second comment. Maybe this could help you in the context of the actual problem to configure things for a stable setup: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34383817/2849346

Comment: @MWiesner thx for your advice and links with examples, it was the problem. For me a little bit unlogical, but config is config ...
Nice 2 meet you, public holiday and happy new year.

Comment: maybe you could accept in case it helped you and things are working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you haven't configured a valid datasource which uses the MySQL backend.

> org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid schema name: REFUGEESWELCOMEAPP

Instead, the TomEE container uses a default backend configuration which is HSQLDB driven by default. This should be changed, have a look at:

1. general information on how to configure datasources correctly here: [tomee.apache.org/datasource-config.html](http://tomee.apache.org/datasource-config.html) and
2. typical configurations at: [tomee.apache.org/common-datasource-configurations.html](http://tomee.apache.org/common-datasource-configurations.html)

A working/similar configuration can be found at this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34383817/2849346):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<Resource id="myDS-Name" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    JtaManaged = true
    DataSourceCreator = tomcat

    validationQuery = SELECT 1
    initialSize = 2
    removeAbandoned = true
    removeAbandonedTimeout = 120

    driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url = jdbc:mysql://someFQDNHostnameOrIP/someDBname
    username = your-username
    password = your-pw
</Resource>
</resources>
```